# Forcing Intel HD Graphics 5000 on a 2013 MacBook Air to output 4K

Tags: mojave, graphics, 4k

I have a late 2013 MacBook Air, running macOS Mojave connected to a 4K Monitor:

```
  Intel HD Graphics 5000:

  Chipset Model: Intel HD Graphics 5000
  Type: GPU
  Bus: Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max): 1536 MB
  Vendor: Intel
  Device ID: 0x0a26
  Revision ID: 0x0009
  Metal: Supported, feature set macOS GPUFamily1 v4
  Displays:
    LG Ultra HD:
      Resolution: 2560 x 1440 (QHD/WQHD - Wide Quad High Definition)
      UI Looks like: 2560 x 1440 @ 59 Hz
      Framebuffer Depth: 24-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
      Automatically Adjust Brightness: No
      Connection Type: DisplayPort
```

I have read on several occasions that this chipset is able to output 4K, but macOS prevents it from doing so.

Is it possible to force my MacBook Air to output 4K?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your 2013 MacBook Air cannot drive a 4K display. MacBook Air 2013 comes with a Thunderbolt 1 controller which supports DisplayPort 1.1. DisplayPort 1.2 is needed to get 4K support.

- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp678)

> #### Graphics and Video Support
>
> - Intel HD Graphics 5000.
> - Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors.

- [Use 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp678)

> You can use 4K displays and Ultra HD TVs with these Mac computers:
>
> - MacBook Air (Early 2015) and later.